# How long does it take for a gene to be switched on or off through the process of epigenetic expression?

Tags: genetics, epigenetics

I understand that in our lifetime, our experiences affect the expression of our genes. Some get switched on, while others switched off. Our experiences, diet, lifestyle etc. determines this expression of genes, but my question is, how long does it roughly take for such an expression to take place? Let's say you are a raging alcoholic suffering from chronic stress. Because of this lifestyle, certain genes get turned on. Then after a decade or two, you decide to change. You start eating healthy, you exercise, you change your lifestyle completely. How long would it now take for your new lifestyle to cause a different gene expression?

I realize this could be a silly question, but this is my understanding of how things work.

Comment: Have you Googled this question searching for [an answer](https://www.cdc.gov/genomics/disease/epigenetics.htm)? One of this site's requirements is that the OP show evidence of searching for an answer (which usually means a quote with a link to the source.) Strange, maybe, for a Q&A site, but it helps us know where you are in understanding a topic. [Not all epigenetic changes are alike](https://www.cdc.gov/genomics/disease/epigenetics.htm); many are permanent, and some are even passed on to offspring!

Comment: If I had found an answer to my question, why would I be posting here? I'm sure the answer can be found somewhere, it's just that I don't want to read 100 pages of hard core research just to find a short 1 sentence answer to my question. Isn't that why Q&A sites exist? I still don't see the answer to my question in the link you provided. I also don't understand what you mean by being epigenetic changes being permanent. My question is not whether they are permanent, but how long does it take for such an expression to take place. Just give me some rough estimate.

Comment: "Isn't that why Q&A sites exist?" Not this answer site, obviously. And if you didn't find the answer in the link I provided, you can't have read it. It addresses your question about smoking exactly, and the other is easily inferred. There are few one-sentence answers in Biology. If they could be answered in one sentence, you should be able to find it very easily.

Comment: The smoking was just an example. I am mainly interested in chronic stress, and what genes could get expressed because of it, and if hypothetically your situation changes, how long would it take before bad genes get muted again.

Comment: Read the link!!!